# Getting only grep exact matches

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep a file for the exact occurrence of a match, but I get also longer spurious matches:

```
grep CAT1717O99 myfile.txt  -F -w
```

Output:

```
CAT1717O99

CAT1717O99.5
```

I would like to output only the first *exactly* matching line. Is there any way to get rid of the second line?
Thanks in advance.
Arturo

This is the file 'myfile.txt':

```
CAT1717O99

CAT1717O99.5
```

Comment: can you show the fragment of `myfile.txt`?

Answer (score 4):

This will do the work for you.

```
grep -Fx "CAT1717O99" textfile
```

-F means Fixed
-x mean exact

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. Still I get the spurious matching line.

Comment: If it did work for you as excepted, then kindly accept the answer to help fellow SO users.

Answer (score 4):

Use the power of *Perl-compatible regular expression* (*PCRE*) and search the matches to the given pattern:

```
grep -Po "\bCAT1717O99(\s|$)" myfile.txt
```

`(\s|$)` - alternative group, ensures matching substring `CAT1717O99` if it's followed by whitespace or placed at the end of the line

`-P` option, allows regular expressions

`-o` option, prints only matched parts of matching lines

Answer (score 2):

You'll need explicitly request spaces in order to ignore special chars.

```
grep -E '(^| )CAT1717O99( |$)' myFile.txt
```

from grep manual :

> **-w, --word-regexp**
>   Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.